# rich text area image in salesforce site

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, richtextarea

I do not achieve to display the images from a rich text area in my site with salesforce.

I want to do that to customize the display. The site is accessible with a specific URL which contains the ID of the distributor (account record type). Then I fetch information from the distributor. This is where I grab the rich text area and I display it as a merge field on the page with an outputText with `escape='false'` (to display the html). But here I have an image with the following text :
Image Not Available
This image is not available because :

- You don't have the privileges to see it, OR
- It has been removed from the system

I'm going in a real complicated workaround and I want to be really sure that I can't do that easily.

The guest user profile is also well set, and it can see the rich text area.

Is there anyone who know how to do it or who has the same problem ?

Comment: It sounds like your path is wrong, do you have any code to look at?

Comment: I don't think it's a path problem because if I open the page in an instance of the browser which has a tab connected to salesforce, the org will take the cookie and display what I want to see. But I want my page to be reachable without connection, this is the purpose of a Site I think. I don't think it's a problem from code, maybe I just don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the image is stored in which object and if the Guest User Profile has access to it or not?

The image might be stored in File, ContentDocument, or related objects. Also if the file is linked to any other parent object, you need to check ContentDocumentLink as well.

After providing access to the said object and record, it should be visible.

Visit https://nonitechsolutions.blogspot.com/2021/06/salesforce-enable-guest-user-on-your.html

Answer (score 0):

Issue is because of "Secure guest user record access" is checked thats why site guest users cannot see the rich text field image.
For this you need to create sharing rule for your custom object.
Make sure to expose data carefully to guest users otherwise it may lead to security issues